# External Accessort Framework - get MAC address of connected devices

Tags: iphone, ipad, external-accessory

i'm new in stackoverflow... this is a good moment to THANK YOU ALL for the great support!

I've a problem... i need to get the MAC address of a connected EAAccessory.
whit this trick i can take it:

```
/* accessory is a connected EAAccessory, obviously */
NSString *macAddress = [accessory valueForKey: @"macAddress"];
```

My problem is that iPad1's accessories (and maybe old iphone) don't have the key "macAddress"... this is very strange.

Any ideas?
THX